# Best place to unwrap optional instance properties--when created or when called?

Tags: swift

When you want to create an instance property that has an initializer that you want to initialize after `self` is available, you typically would make it a variable and declare it as an option, like so:

```
var mapView: MGLMapView?
```

And then when `self` is available, you would initialize it, like so:

```
mapView = MGLMapView(frame: view.bounds)
```

However, when you later call `mapView`, should you call it with `?` or `!`

```
mapView?.userTrackingMode = .follow
mapView!.userTrackingMode = .follow
```

Or should it be unwrapped right when the property is first created, like so:

```
var mapView: MGLMapView!
```

And then forego any use of `?` or `!` thereafter. All three possibilities will compile and run so is there a best practice or rules of thumb to follow when having to choose?

Comment: " create an instance property that has an initializer that you want to initialize after self is available" what do you mean by "after self is available"?

Comment: After self is available as in not before self is available (i.e. property initializers run before self is available).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variable should be declared as implicitly unwrapped (using `!`) only when you will be assigning a value outside of an `init` but before all of your other code will access the variable, and the variable will definitely be given a value.

Typical examples of this are outlets in a view controller. The values are assigned after `init` but before all other code will make use of them. In this case `awakeFromNib` or `viewDidLoad` is a typical place for the initialization. Since all other code can safely assume the variable has a non-nil value, the use of the implicitly unwrapped variable makes sense.

For "normal" optionals (using `?` in the declaration), you should never force-unwrap those value since the whole reason the variable is an optional is because it might be `nil`.

In these cases, always use conditional binding (`if let`) or optional chaining.

In your example, you will most likely setup the map view in the `viewDidLoad` method so declare it as `var mapView: MGLMapView!`. Then you can reference `mapView` like it's not an optional everywhere else in your code. Just make sure you don't attempt to access `mapView` before `viewDidLoad` initializes it.

Another option is to set up the property as a lazily loaded property. Then you don't need it to be declared with either `?` or `!`.

Comment: I like the `lazy var` option (pun) the most.

Answer (score 2):

If we assume that MapView will be initialized when controller loads, we can then also assume that all subsequent references will not be nil and that we can implicitly unwrap MapView.

Therefore a valid approach is to declare mapView as follows

```
var mapView: MGLMapView!
```

This is referred to as an implicitly unwrapped option and then you may reference it directly as below (provided there is no possibility of mapView being set to nil elsewhere)

```
mapView.userTrackingMode = .follow
```

There is a section in the Swift Programming Language by Apple entitled "Implicity Unwrapped Optionals" which will go into further detail.

You can also write code other ways as you have indicated - the important thing to consider is whether or not there is a possibility of the mapView variable being nil when it is unwrapped.  If not, use above.

You will also notice that the interface builder within XCode also makes use of implicitly unwrapped variables when referencing UI components (labels, textboxes, etc) which gives me confidence that this is an appropriate approach.